# In Umbraco 7.2 how do I show the other side of a multi-node tree picker relationship?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Using Umbraco 7.2

I have a multi-node tree picker property on Members that shows to which of a specific type of content each member is related. Is there an existing data type or other established method I can use on the *related* content to show the members?

So I have this: Member1 -> Content1, Content2, Content3

How do I show this: Content1 -> Member1, Member2, Member3

Ideally only using the one multi-node tree picker to establish and manage the relationship

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the Umbraco Relations API for this type of 2-way relationship.

See the following links:

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/12/7/getting-to-know-umbraco-relations

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/management/Relations/